# Profiting off $0.01 changes in real life?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Recently, I have been getting more into stock games, and stocks like $FTR the past few days have been pretty rampant in our game. A few people ended at around 1,000 trades and nearly tripled their money. Again, these are off a ton of $0.01 changes every minute, and use of limit orders (limit buy @ $2.09, wait till it is bought, limit sell @ $2.10, after sell, repeat). Is this possible to repeat in real life?

Comment: What if, instead of going up this time, it never again hits $2.10? What if the company goes bankrupt?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton this was more a theoretical question, but I see your point that it's incredibly risky. EDIT: I know that my comment was ironic that I say "real life" in the post but theoretical in the comment, but I meant theoretical as in the "is this possible" rather than actually theoretical.

Comment: Anything is possible.  HFT firms clear wheelbarrows of money every day capitalizing on small movements.  Can you do it, alone, with retail access to the market and a small bankroll? Probably not.

Comment: What do you mean by retail access to the market? Does having a slower system actually decrease the times for trades by such a substantial amount to the extent that you couldn't make money?

Comment: This is a reverse lottery. You make a very small profit, but take a very small chance at a *massive* loss. Say you bought at 2.09 and are waiting for the price to hit $2.10, and say it drops to 2.08, and then 2.07, and then 2.06. When do you accept the loss? It might go back to $2.10 in just a few more minutes. Now you've got your money tied up for a long time hoping that you can break even. (I trade like this and right now I have a trade I expect to make about $14 from that's down $210 and tying up $35,000. That's not atypical.)

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly *try* to do this, but it's risky and very expensive.

Consider a simplified example. You buy 1000 shares of ABC at $1.00 each, with the intention of selling them all when the price reaches $1.01. Rinse and repeat, right?

### Commissions

You might think the example above will net you a tidy $10 profit. But you have to factor in trade commissions. Most brokerages are going to charge you *per trade*. Fidelity for example, want $4.95 per trade; that's for both the buying *and* the selling. So your 1000 shares actually cost you $1004.95, and then when you sell them for $1.01 each, they take their $4.95 fee again, leaving you with a measly $1.10 in profit. Meanwhile, your entire $1000 stake was at risk of never making ANY profit - you may have been unlucky enough to buy at the stock's peak price before a slow (or even fast) decline towards eventual bankruptcy.

### Required Volatility

The other problem with this is that you need a stock that is both stable and volatile *at the same time*. You need the volatility to ensure the price keeps swinging between your buy and sell thresholds, over and over again. You need stability to ensure it doesn't move well away from those thresholds altogether.

If it doesn't have this weird stable-volatility thing, then you are shooting yourself in the foot by not holding the stock for longer: why sell for $1.01 if it goes up to $1.10 ten minutes later? Why buy for $1.00 when it keeps dropping to $0.95 ten minutes later? Your strategy means you are always taking the *smallest* possible profit, for the *same* amount of risk.

Another method might be to only trade each stock once, and hope that you never pick a loser. Perhaps look for something that has been steadily climbing in price, buy, make your tiny profit, then move on to the next company. However you still have the risk of buying something at it's peak price and being in for an awfully long wait before you can cash out (if ever).

And if all that wasn't enough to put you off, brokerages have special rules for "frequent traders" that just make it all the more complicated. Not worth the hassle IMO.

Comment: Ok, cool. Bid/ask prices aren't relevant then, right? Assuming you had a stock that had the necessary stable/volatile mix and no commision?

Comment: If you can find a brokerage that will let you trade for no commission please share it here; you'll be everyones best friend! Bid/Ask are somewhat relevant, it all comes down to your risk tolerance. You would probably want a bigger margin between your buy/sell limits to maximize profit and minimize the impact of commissions, but this will come with a longer (possibly infinite) wait for the market price to reach each of those thresholds.

Comment: I believe Robinhood is commissionless, but this was more out of curiosity then actually a plan. I wasn't sure whether a bid/ask difference of 1cent would make it impossible to profit on changes of 1 cent because I'm quite new to all of the intricacies of investing. Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: Robinhood offers $0 commissions. I did this once just to try it. I profited $.10 in 10 minutes while tying up $10,000 for three days. I know a way to make money faster than 0.2% per year.